# Instantiating the python class from Same file vs different file vs __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie to python, 
Q1 : I am wondering, Why print statement is executing multiple times, even though I called `school1.print_name()` only once?

Q2 : What is purpose of `__init__.py` that is being created when creating a new 
     package?

Q3 : What difference does it make creating an object from `otherfile.py` and 
    `__init__.py`?

(Note:  I debugged the code from otherfile.py and **init**.py, where the script is not terminating after calling the  school1.print_name(), but it is running again from the start of script)

**SameFile.py**

```
class School:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print("School name is : " + self.name)

school1 = School("DPS") # 1 
school1.print_name()`   # 2
# These 1 and 2 lines are removed from this file when running from otherfile.py and __init__.py
```

o/p :

```
School name is : DPS
```

**OtherFile.py**

```
import School

school1 = School("DPS")
school1.print_name()
```

o/p :

```
School name is : DPS
School name is : DPS #why did it print second time
```

**__init__.py**

```
import School

school1 = School("DPS")
school1.print_name()
```

o/p :

```
School name is : DPS
School name is : DPS #why did it print second time
```

Comment: You should add `if __name__ == "__main__"` to the file that defines the class `School`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) post. Give your school different names across files to see what is actually happening!

Comment: Thanks @rinkert !! Figured it out, What exactly happening.
Appreciated :)

Comment: In `__init__.py`
Suppose...

`school1 = School("DPS -- __init__")`
`school1.print_name()`

--------------------------------


O/P: 
`School name is : DPS -- __init__`
`School name is : DPS -- __init__`

Its printing multiple times now? Whats happening now ?

Comment: You can best leave your `__init__.py` empty, add the name == main to the file that defines `School`, and do an `import School` at the top of the files that require `School`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following file structure:

```
mymodule/
    __init__.py
    Buildings.py
```

Let's keep `__init__.py` empty for the moment. `Buildings.py` looks as follows:

```
class School:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print("School name is : " + self.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    school1 = School("DPS -- Buildings.py")
    school1.print_name()
```

Use your module in a file `test.py` as follows:

```
from mymodule.Buildings import School

school = School('DPS - test.py')
school.print_name()
```

This will correctly print `DPS - test.py`, as we would expect. Since `__init__.py` is empty, nothing else will be printed. If we however put any print statement in the `__init__.py`, this will be displayed when importing anything from the `mymodule` module.

Change `__init__.py`:

```
from mymodule.Buildings import School 

print('__init__.py is loaded!')

school = School('DPS - __init__.py')
school.print_name()
```

and run `test.py`, which will result in the following output:

```
__init__.py is loaded!
School name is : DPS - __init__.py
School name is : DPS - test.py
```

So you can see, that first `__init__.py` is executed upon loading of the module, and then the other lines in `test.py` are executed.

Comment: Yes this is fine @rinkert!!
suppose If I am running code from `__init__.py`,
then output goes like this:
---------------------
`__init__.py is loaded!` ......
`School name is : DPS - __init__.py` .....
`__init__.py is loaded!` .....
`School name is : DPS - __init__.py`

The output is printed multiple times

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module, functions in that module are executed. To prevent this problem you can use `if **name** == "main":

```
class School:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print("School name is : " + self.name)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    school1 = School("DPS") # 1 
    school1.print_name()`   # 2
```

For Q2 and Q3 refer this question:
[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for/448311)

Comment: Functions in a module aren't executed on import with or without `if __name__ == "__main__"` unless those functions are executed in the modules `__init__.py`

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe, can I know where exactly you are linking the above point ?
thanks

Comment: @RahulReddy the comment says "When you import a module, functions in that module are executed' this is incorrect unless those functions are specified to run in the modules `__init__`.py file. `if __name__ ==  "__main__":` has nothing to do with what happens when the file is imported but rather when the file is run at the command line as a standalone script